# building a remotely controlled remote controlled car :)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, infrared, robotics

I am a newb to EE (I am a web developer). My friend works remotely and this is what I would like to accomplish:

1. Build a web interface like this:

[image]

2. When he visits this interface from a remote location, he can press the buttons and (using an infrared signal emitter on our end) control a remote control car with a camera on it.

Any idea if something like this can be accomplished with standard web technologies? I have never done anything with robotics but I have heard about things like Arduino and tools like Raspberry Pi.

Just looking for some basic suggestions to point me in the right direction.

Comment: You don't want to use IR. IR is LoS, and remote control vehicles are really fun when they go out of LoS.

Comment: Video return from the car is probably the hardest part to build and the thing that should be built first, probably using a Pi webcam over wifi. Once you have that you can add features to control the car over the same IP channel. You'll want a slow car due to Mars-rover levels of latency.

Comment: Thanks guys. Ignacio, I didn't understand your comment about "LoS." What is LoS and if infrared is not the best choice, any thoughts about what is? Much appreciated. pjc50, thanks for your thoughts about video considerations

Comment: LoS = Line of Sight

Comment: I actually did this exact project when I started out in electronics. Some of the design decisions I made make me cringe to this day but feel free to look at it: http://www.instructables.com/id/Reginald-a-UDP-surveillance-bot-control-via-the-/

Comment: Tinkernut did something like that on YouTube. This may give you a place to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xt-rrH04O2g&safe=active

Comment: @NickWilliams As a first project it's not all that bad, especially not if you have stayed critical as you say you have. As an instructable it's definitely above par. My notes would include cheaper sources for electronic parts and/or some alternatives and some doubt you needed the "extra precise" bearings. But as said, certainly not a bad way to go at all. You may allow yourself some pride, if not just for actually doing it.

Comment: Wow Nick! I couldn't ask for more. Thanks a lot everyone, obviously this gives me plenty of information to begin the learning process.